# One Select statement for criteria of one column with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I want to make a SQL SELECT statement that selects multiple rows based on the value of one column, but I have a list of valid values that match the rows I want to select.

Specifically, I have a list of user IDs. I want to select the entire row for every row that has a user id that is in this list (this list is in PHP, and I'm also making the SQL calls from there).

My code so far, looks like this:

```
$list_of_ids = array(1, 5, 7, 23);//list of user ids I want to select.
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=?????", ????);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: you can used foreach loop it may be help for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ids = implode(',',$list_of_ids);
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users where user_id in ($ids)");
```

Comment: Perfect! I thought that I would have to loop through and make something like SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 2 OR user_id = 3 OR ...

Comment: yes but i would say in that case you could do a `count($list_of_ids)` and if you've only got one element then you may as well do a `where user_id = $id;` in the query for performance.

Comment: an emtpy resultset you mean? can you do an echo of the query itself?

Answer (score 1):

Convert array in comma separated string like this:

```
  $list_of_ids = array(1, 5, 7, 23);
  $out = implode(",", $list_of_ids) ;
  $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id in =(".$out.")");
```

Comment: It should be without the sprinf, which is actually spelled sprintf